# g++: How to unmangle exported symbols

Tags: java, g++, java-native-interface, name-mangling

I'm trying to compile a Java library that uses JNI. When I start the program, I see a crash with an UnsatisfiedLinkError, which says that a particular method could not be found in the DLL.

On closer inspection, I found out that g++, which I use for compilation and linking, mangled my method names by adding suffixes such as "@8" or "@16" to the method names. Does anybody know the correct compiler options to disable the name mangling? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I'm using MinGW through Eclipse + CDT plugin.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For JNI calls to work with Windows DLLs compiled with GCC you need to add a add-stdcall-alias parameter to GCC on linking phase:

```
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias
```

Which will add correct function names to the DLL and thus enable calls via JNI.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has finally solved my problem. With this parameter, there's a decorated and an undecorated version for each method in the DLL, and the Java programs works :D

Comment: @Mavrik thank you for filling this in, I knew the problem but not the solution.

Comment: So this works for other cases than just underscores in mangled names?